# Configuring a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multiprocessing.Process called `Sim` which has the following run method:

```
def run():
  self.servers = [TcpServer(p, resps[p].get) for p in ports]
  for s in self.servers: s.start()
  self.event.wait()
  for s in self.servers: s.stop()
```

`TcpServer` inherits from threading.Thread.

`resps` is a dict of responders for each port. An example of a responder's get method is as follows:

```
def get(data):
    rsp = MyRsp()
    rsp.a = 1
    rsp.b = 1  
    rsp.c = 1  
    rsp.d = 1 if data[0] == 1 else 2   
    return rsp
```

What I'd like to do is change the behaviour of a responder while the `Sim` process is running and I wish to do this from the Main process. For example I might like to change the above responder so that `rsp.b = 2` instead.

Note that a responder can also have state:

```
class Rsp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None

    def get(data):
        if data[0] = "update":
            self.state = data[1]
            return "updated"
        else:
            assert data[0] == "get"
            return self.state
```

How might I solve this? The only idea I have is to run an additional thread in my `Sim` process which reads from a multiprocessing.Queue. The main process can then add data for a given port which the thread can use to update the responder. Am I on the right track?

I'm forced to implemented my networking in its own process.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the network part, but if the variables you need to change have a fixed type, you could put them in a `multiprocessing.Array`, wich is a shared variable. You should also use the built-in Lock to acces it. If you think it might work, I can develop the idea

Comment: @HarryPotfleur Yes, I'd like to see you develop your idea please!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work, as I don't fully understand what you ar trying to do, but you might use shared memory, for example a shared array:

```
from multiprocessing import Array

# Declare you shared array in your main
rsp=Array('f',4) # Create a (4,1) array of floats

# You need to pass the shared array as argument to the Processes that will need it

# to access data:
rsp.acquire() # Lock the shared memory to avoid conflicts. If already Locked by another Process, will also wait until memory is released.
a=rsp[0] # get the data or modify it like any other array
b=rsp[1]
...
rsp.release() # Release the Lock to allow other process the access
```

I don't think this is the prettiest solution but it might do the trick. You should also take a look at `Multiprocessing.Manager`, I never used it but I think it it designed just for cases like this one.